# Parent Child (Save, Update and Delete)

Tags: nhibernate

I have a two tables set up as Parent/Child e.g Customer and Address (holding either one record which is both billing and shipping record or 2 records - one billing and one shipping record). Saving a new parent child is not an issue. 
The issue comes when the user needs to update his details. He has two addresses that he specified when he registered. On the edit screen now, he says his billing address is same as shipping address. How do I delete the second address as well as update his details in other address and his customer details.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt response. I will make the changes and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You do this in a [transaction.](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/transactions.html)

```
begin transaction
    delete second address.
    update first address
    update other details.
end transaction
```

The example you might be interested in on that page is:

```
// foo is an instance loaded by a previous Session
foo.Property = "bar";
session = factory.OpenSession();
transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
session.SaveOrUpdate(foo);
session.Flush();
transaction.Commit();
session.Close();
```

Comment: You should use using blocks for sessions and transactions ;)